# Creating gist directly from Jupyper notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gist

Is there any way to create gist directly from Jupyter notebook?

This would be really handy as it would allow load gist and load it's url directly to nbwiever without leading opening terminal or IDE.

Comment: this might interest you: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/gist_it

Comment: Yes it would. thanks @cel !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/mozilla/jupyter-notebook-gist which does exactly what you want. The docs are good on how to **install** it but aren't specific on exactly how to **use** it.

However, once you install it you see that it adds this menu, which you just click:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Actually, you can just drag and drop the Jupyter notebook (or Jupyterlab) file (.ipynb) into the 'code space' on the Gist site. So,

1. Go to https://gist.github.com/YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME/
2. Click 'New Gist' on the upper right corner
3. Open the folder in a Finder/Explorer window on your local computer
4. Drag the file into the text box (the 'code space'). This should fill the space with JSON looking text for the framework of the notebook content.
5. Copy/Paste the full file name (e.g., mynotebook.ipynb) into the filename box, and give a description above.
6. Create the Gist!

Comment: The title of this question is _"Creating gist **directly** from Jupyper notebook?"_ (emphasis is mine).  Do you really think that yours is an answer to this question?

Comment: @gboffi while technically not, this answer helped me, and apparently at least 12 people more - and it's the highest ranking answer. Do you really think your comment is necessary for this answer?